# Div's inside Div not aligning Horizontally

Tags: html, css, alignment

I have a div that holds multiple other divs in order to keep them consistent, everything is working well besides as they go down, the divs seem to be becoming more narrow on both left and right. I want each to be aligned on left and right as they go down vertically, instead of being pushed in on the left and right as they go down. Thanks anyone who can give it a try.

The site is here: http://runnerdetroit.run/runnerNEWS.html

and the code is ( of course I didnt include all the code, just what I feel is necessary to share):

**CSS**

```css
.fixedwidth2 {width:1126px; height: 98%; margin:0 auto; margin-bottom: 45px; margin-top: 
     120px; } 


   .leftimage { float: left; width: 30%; margin-right: 15px; margin-left: 7px; }

    .leftimage img {width: 100%;}

     .righttext { float:left; width: 67.5%; }

     .box {margin-left: 0px;   }

     #left-div {

    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-top: 60px;
    margin-bottom: 2000px;
    line-height: 22px;
    }

    #headline { float: left; margin-top: 0px; margin-left: 10px; width: 98%; height: 150px; 
    margin-bottom:100px;      }
```

```
**HTML**
```

```html
   <div class="box">

   <div class="fixedwidth2">

   <div id="left-div">

   <div id="headline">


    <h><li><a href="EngagagementsofAlterity.html"><em>Engagements of Alterity</em></a></li>. 
    </</h>

    <div class="leftimage">
    <img src="images/article images/EngagementsofAlterirt/0bce0e8e-336a- 
    47719773f506865aa7a2.jpg" 
    alt= Engagements of Alterity RUNNER 2020 title=EngagementsofAlterity.AshleyCook >
    </div>
             <div class="righttext">
    <p>What would it mean, as contemporary moderns, to recognize these areas, the hybrids, the 
    blocks of movement of something which is in transition between what it was and what it will 
    be?  As many contemporary philosophers and anthropologists are beginning to see this need 
    for control as paradoxical and highly problematic, they are asking “how do we break from 
    these tendencies?” And "what kinds of potential comes with the suspension of our need for 
     control?"..</p>
             <p>Ashley Cook</p>

            <p>June 8, 2020</p>

            <p><i>thought</i></p>

            </div>


    <div id="headline">
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>

    <h><li><a href="ScienceNonFiction2020.html"><em>Science Non-Fiction: 2020</em></a></li>. 
    </</h>

    <div class="leftimage">
    <img src="images/article images/Science Non-Fiction/Untitled8.png" alt= Science Non-Fiction: 
    2020 RUNNER 2020 title=SpeechSoundsLive.Perlex >
            </div>
             <div class="righttext">
           <p>Among the newest array of online zoom meetings and virtual dance parties, in the 
    ether of the net, exists a 115 minute ambient music set weaved intermittently with a reading 
    of Octavia E. Butler’s <em>Speech Sounds</em>. Composed by Perlex, <em>Speech Sounds 
    Live</em> was presented as part of the BLDG:01 live streaming project called Stille....</p>
             <p>Ashley Cook</p>

            <p>May 25, 2020</p>

            <p><i>music</i></p>

            </div>

    <div id="headline">
             <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>

     <h><li><a href="AnInterviewWithNolanSimon.html"><em>An Interview with Nolan Simon</em></a>. 
    </li></</h>

    <div class="leftimage">
    <img src="images/article images/NS for Virginia Torrence/Panagia Orans, Oranta copy.jpg" 
    alt= An Interview with Nolan Simon by Virginia Torrence RUNNER 2020 
     title=PanagiaOrans,Oranta >
            </div>
     <div class="righttext">
     <p>Nolan Simon (b. 1980) lives and works in Hamtramck, Michigan. His work has been included 
    in exhibitions across the US and Europe, including solo shows at 47 Canal in New York City, 
    Lars Friedrich in Berlin, Rieseburo Galerie Christian Nagel in Cologne, Green Gallery in 
    Milwaukee and at What Pipeline in Detroit. Nolan and I met in his studio at CAVE, a 
    collective art studio located in the Russell Industrial Center...</p>
             <p>Virginia Torrence</p>

            <p>May 11, 2020</p>

            <p><i>art</i></p>

            </div>



   <div id="headline">

                         <p>&nbsp;</p>
                         <p>&nbsp;</p>


  <h><li><a href="TheImportanceOfAMirrortToADancer.html"><em>The Importance of a Mirror to a Dancer</em></a></li></</h>



  <p>“Conscious awareness is a powerful tool to transcending unconscious patterns. It fosters an expanded perspective and openness to new possibilities. It is a process of recognizing what is going on inside and out, the effects of decisions and actions, and the interaction between the complex array of factors and forces. It is seeing, observing our thoughts, recognizing our feelings and the effect they are having on us and others; it functions as...</p>

            <p>Ashley Cook</p>

            <p>April 24, 2020</p>

      <p><i>culture</i></p>

           </div>



          </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: EDIT ON THE TITLE! I MEANT DIVS INSIDE DIV NOT ALIGNING VERTICALLY, as I would like them to.

Comment: try using flex: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you are looking for. You had some unclosed divs and I tidied up the code a bit.

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .fixedwidth2 {width:1126px; height: 98%; margin:0 auto; margin-bottom: 45px; margin-top: 
            120px; } 
            .leftimage img {width: 100%;}
            .righttext { float:left; width: 67.5%; }
            .box {margin-left: 0px;   }
            #left-div {
                float: left;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                margin-right: 0px;
                margin-left: 0px;
                margin-top: 60px;
                margin-bottom: 2000px;
                line-height: 22px;
            }
            #headline { float: left; margin-top: 0px; margin-left: 10px; width: 98%; height: 150px; margin-bottom:100px;} 
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h><li><a href="EngagagementsofAlterity.html"><em>Engagements of Alterity</em></a></li></h>
        <div class="leftimage">
            <img src="images/article images/EngagementsofAlterirt/0bce0e8e-336a-47719773f506865aa7a2.jpg" alt= Engagements of Alterity RUNNER 2020 title=EngagementsofAlterity.AshleyCook >
        </div>
        <div class="righttext">
        <p>What would it mean, as contemporary moderns, to recognize these areas, the hybrids, the 
        blocks of movement of something which is in transition between what it was and what it will 
        be?  As many contemporary philosophers and anthropologists are beginning to see this need 
        for control as paradoxical and highly problematic, they are asking “how do we break from 
        these tendencies?” And "what kinds of potential comes with the suspension of our need for 
        control?"..
        </p>
        <p>Ashley Cook</p>
        <p>June 8, 2020</p>
        <p><i>thought</i></p>
        </div>
        <div id="headline">
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <h><li><a href="ScienceNonFiction2020.html"><em>Science Non-Fiction: 2020</em></a></li></h></div>
            <div class="leftimage">
                <img src="images/article images/Science Non-Fiction/Untitled8.png" alt= Science Non-Fiction: 2020 RUNNER 2020 title=SpeechSoundsLive.Perlex >
                <div class="righttext">
                <p>Among the newest array of online zoom meetings and virtual dance parties, in the 
                ether of the net, exists a 115 minute ambient music set weaved intermittently with a reading 
                of Octavia E. Butler’s <em>Speech Sounds</em>. Composed by Perlex, <em>Speech Sounds 
                Live</em> was presented as part of the BLDG:01 live streaming project called Stille....</p>
                <p>Ashley Cook</p>
                <p>May 25, 2020</p>
                <p><i>music</i></p>
                </div>
        <div id="headline">
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <h><li><a href="AnInterviewWithNolanSimon.html"><em>An Interview with Nolan Simon</em></a></li></h></div>
            <div class="leftimage">
                <img src="images/article images/NS for Virginia Torrence/Panagia Orans, Oranta copy.jpg" alt= An Interview with Nolan Simon by Virginia Torrence RUNNER 2020 title=PanagiaOrans,Oranta >
            </div>
            <div class="righttext">
            <p>Nolan Simon (b. 1980) lives and works in Hamtramck, Michigan. His work has been included 
            in exhibitions across the US and Europe, including solo shows at 47 Canal in New York City, 
            Lars Friedrich in Berlin, Rieseburo Galerie Christian Nagel in Cologne, Green Gallery in 
            Milwaukee and at What Pipeline in Detroit. Nolan and I met in his studio at CAVE, a 
            collective art studio located in the Russell Industrial Center...</p>
            <p>Virginia Torrence</p>
            <p>May 11, 2020</p>
            <p><i>art</i></p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```